# Create a new symlink for files in a folder

Tags: linux, bash, shell, symlink

I have a folder and it has files as below:

```
ls  /opt/data/incoming/test1
```

**doc1.txt**

**doc2.txt**

And I want to create a symlink for my folder test2 in following path:
`/run/opt/corp/mydir/test2`

I tried to do with following command:

```
ln -sn  /opt/data/incoming/test1 /run/opt/corp/mydir/test2
```

But it didn't give me what I want. The symlinked file looks like:

```
ls /run/opt/corp/mydir/test2
```

**test1**

I was expecting to see files not folder. Here what I was expecting to see:

```
ls /run/opt/corp/mydir/test2
```

**doc1.txt**

**doc2.txt**

Could you please help to fix it?
Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding wildcard in order to reference files inside of your source directory:

```
ln -s  /opt/data/incoming/test1/* /run/opt/corp/mydir/test2
```